# pass yes/no parameter to a query in MS Access from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

```
tblCategory c=new tblCategory();     
OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
            cm.Connection = AccessConnection();
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cm.CommandText = "instblCategory";
            cm.Parameters.Add("vCategoryName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c.CategoryName;
            cm.Parameters.Add("vdtCreated", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c.DtCreated;
            cm.Parameters.Add("vIsActive", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = c.IsActive;
            cm.Parameters.Add("vDescription", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c.Description;
            if (!Exist(c))
            {
                cm.Connection.Open();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cm.Connection.Close();
            }
```

I get an error at cm.ExecuteNonQuery(). The is "Datatype mismatch".
I tried passing only one parameter at a time and i found that passing boolean value causes error.

Please advice me on how to pass a boolean value to a query in MS Access using C#?

Comment: What is the signature of your StoredProcedure?

Comment: By the way, I would suggest using AddWithValue rather than Add in that scenario.  Use a value of the correct type and the parameter data type is inferred, e.g. `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("vCategoryName", c.CategoryName);`

Comment: What is the data type of vIsActive on your ms access and IsActive on your code?

Comment: The signature of my storeprocedure is Insert.

Comment: I also tried using AddWithValue but no luck.

Comment: Datatype of vIsActive is yes/no in MS Access and the datatype of IsActive in my code is bool

Comment: How do you know that the problem is on `vIsActive` and not on `vdtCreated`?  What are `vdtCreated` and `c.DtCreated` data types?

Comment: vdtCreated is varchar and c.DtCreated is string. I know the problem is in vIsActive because, i tried to insert by passing only one parameter at a time. I got error when i tried passing vIsActive

Answer (score -1):

For Access database Yes/No fields are required:

- Yes = -1 Value //Yes means -1
- No = 0 Value //No means 0

in CheckBox Event write code

```
int checkboxevent ;
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        checkboxevent = -1; 
    else
        checkboxevent = 0;
}
```

Pass the check box value to the Access Database. Write the query like this:

```
Query = "insert into Test001 (checkbox) values ( '" + checkboxevent + "')";
```

Comment: No, never write a query like that.  Always use parameters.